# Fitting child div inside parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dimension

As usual I have a parent and child div. Dimensions of a child div is not fixed. On click event I want to change dimensions of a child div to fit perfectly inside a parent div.

**Note:** This is same as pdf viewer fit page feature

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Click</a>

<div id="parent">
    <div id="child4" class="child"></div>
    <!-- Please check by commenting childs one by one
    <div id="child2" class="child"></div>
    <div id="child3" class="child"></div>
    <div id="child4" class="child"></div>
    -->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {width:200px; height:100px; margin:100px auto; border:1px solid #000; overflow:auto}
.child {margin:0; border:1px solid #000; background-color:maroon; opacity:0.5}

#child1 {width:100px; height:50px}
#child2 {width:400px; height:100px}
#child3 {width:100px; height:500px}
#child4 {width:400px; height:500px}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    // Fit block
    $("a").click(function(){
        //I want logic here to fit $(".child") div perfectly
        //inside $("#parent") div. After changes dimensions
        //of child should be in proportion to its original width/height.
        //if height is more
        //then it should get parents height and if width is more
        //than it should get parents width but there should be no
        //vertical or horizontal scroll

        $(".child").height($("#parent").height() - 20);
    });
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/LaT3E/4/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not want child div to be exactly like parent div. It is ok if there is gap around child div either horizontally or vertically. Such that newHeight/newWidth = oldHeight/newWidth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to how CSS `background-size:contain;` works?

Here is the solution:

```
$(function(){

var $child = $('.child'),     
    h = $child.height(),
    w = $child.width(),
    bw = $child.css('border-width').replace('px',''),
    parH = $('#parent').height(),
    parW = $('#parent').width(),
    car = w / h, 
    par = parW / parH,
    newH,
    newW;

$('a').click(function(){
    if(car > par){
        newW = parW;
        newH = h / w * newW;    
    }else{
         newH = parH;
         newW = w / h * newH;
    }

    $child.width(newW-bw*2);
    $child.height(newH-bw*2);

    console.log(w+'X'+h+' to '+newW+'X'+newH)
});
});
```

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/uL6pp/5/).

Comment: Yes sorry, I've updated my answer and fiddle. It's now working on all 4 child.

Comment: Please check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uL6pp/7/. It has your code. Only thing I have changed is height of parent. It does not work for child1.

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer but forgot the fiddle. We need to compare the aspect ratio or the diagonal of the child to its parent. Here see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/uL6pp/8/)

Comment: cool !! ... understood what you are doing here. Implemented successfully. Thanks a lot.